# Absolute positioned responsive navigation menu slide body

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu

My basic HTML structure is like this:

body

```
-header
-div
--searchform
-/div
-nav
-/header    
-content
-footer
```

On smaller screens I position my *searchform* and *nav* absolutely and bring it to the top of the page, but hide it initially. On tap of my menu or search button, the searchform and nav should be displayed on top of the page but not overlapping my page content. They should animate down smoothly as well as the rest of the page.

I tried so many things but I can't get it working because they are part of the header.

Comment: Absolute positioning will always overlapp the page content. Should consider using a different type of positioning scheme if you want it to push the page down

Comment: you could create an empty hidden div at the top of your body, move the header and search form into it and then just do a slide down that div, then you will not have the need for absolutely positioning

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I now use jquery to clone my nav to an empty div which I let slideDown() then.